# how to store values in the Textview after parsing in android

Tags: android, web-services-enhancements

Hello i had read the webservise tutorial in android from this link
http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-parsing-web-service-response-part-1/
Plz check(***Parsing the response with SAX Parser:***) in the tutorial

Buti don't know how to store the result in textview in my emmulator so that we can View the result.

Answer (score 2):

```
EditText myResult = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
myResult.setText(mySaxResult);
```

Comment: ...the parsed result - 

what text do you want to see in the edit text?